# JavaScript loop pulling in the same image from Instagram's API

Tags: javascript, loops, each, instagram

I am using Instagram's API to display all recent photos with a certain hashtag. I have a banner which displays all tags successfully and am using it as the background of the banner. I'd like to overlay the 5 recent photos from the hashtag. The code below is what I have so far, but unfortunately the loop displays 5 of the same image.

Here is an image of what I have so far: 
[image]

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: true,
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/gymspotter/media/recent?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        success: function(data) {
            var tagged_photos = [];
            $.each(data.data, function(i, tag){
              tagged_photo = tag.images.thumbnail.url;
              $("#instagram-tagged-showcase").append('<img src="'+tagged_photo+'">')
              if(i < 5) { tagged_photos[i] = tag.images.thumbnail.url; }
            });

            $.each(tagged_photos, function(i, tag){
              $("#instagram-tagged-feed").append('<li class="instagram-tagged-li"><img src="'+tagged_photos+'" class="instagram-tagged-photo"></li>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: on your second each shouldn´t it be: `tagged_photos[i]` ?

Comment: Like this? `$.each(tagged_photos[i], function(i, tag){` - doesn't seem to work

Comment: Your second `each` loops over `tagged_photos`, but it uses neither `i` nor `tag` inside the function; it just repeatedly uses `tagged_photos`. It's not clear what your loop is doing if you're not using your looping variables.

Comment: no, `<img src="'+tagged_photos[i]+'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `+tag+` instead of `+tagged_photos+` in the second loop

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: true,
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/gymspotter/media/recent?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        success: function(data) {
            var tagged_photos = [];
            $.each(data.data, function(i, tag){
              tagged_photo = tag.images.thumbnail.url;
              $("#instagram-tagged-showcase").append('<img src="'+tagged_photo+'">')
              if(i < 5) { tagged_photos[i] = tag.images.thumbnail.url; }
            });

            $.each(tagged_photos, function(i, tag){
              $("#instagram-tagged-feed").append('<li class="instagram-tagged-li"><img src="'+tag+'" class="instagram-tagged-photo"></li>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```